# create file with ffap if it doesn't exist

Tags: ffap

Suppose I have a path like `/path/to/file/` in the buffer. I'd like to put point over that path and invoke a command that will either open it if it exists or create it if it doesn't.

**Edit 1**
Thanks to @Drew for pointing out that /path/to/file/ ends with a slash. I meant /path/to/file which is a file, not a directory.

Also, in my case `M-x ffap` on `/tmp/non-existing-file` will wait for user input at the minibuffer with the following prompt `Find file or URL: /tmp/`

[image]

**Edit 2**

Here's what I tried

```
(defun ffap-create-file ()
  "find or create file at point"
  (interactive)
  (setq filename (ffap-string-at-point))
  (ffap filename))
```

This code works, but it doesn't prompt. The "usual" behavior of ffap is to prompt the user with the filename already populated in the minibuffer.

Answer (score 1):

Just `M-x ffap` does what you want, no?  If so, just bind it to some key:

```lisp
(global-set-key `C-o` #'ffap)
```

That puts you in a buffer for the new file (or new directory, if, as you show, you use a final slash). Just do what you want in that buffer, then save it, if it's for a file.  Or if it's for a directory then (as the message tells you when you create the buffer), use `M-x make-directory RET RET` to create the directory.

This command will take care of creating the directory as well:

```lisp
(defun my-ffap (file/dir)
  "..."
  (interactive (progn (require 'ffap) (list (ffap-prompter))))
  (when (directory-name-p file/dir) (make-directory file/dir t))
  (find-file file/dir))
```

Comment: In my case `M-x ffap` on `/tmp/non-existing-file` will wait for user input at the minibuffer with the following prompt `Find file or URL: /tmp/`

Comment: Did you try `my-ffap`? For me, it fills the minibuffer with the file name the cursor is on.

Comment: same with `my-ffap`, no automatic entry in the minibuffer. See https://imgur.com/a/rsunUdL. It could be that my emacs version is too old (24.3.1)

Comment: same if I use code of ffap-prompter from [emacs github mirror](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/3af9e84ff59811734dcbb5d55e04e1fdb7051e77/lisp/ffap.el)

Comment: Here's what I tried https://gist.github.com/ychaouche/0428f902f00dd3c30ec1d74e5ac76c9c. It works, except it doesn't prompt.

Comment: If you're using Emacs 24.3.1 then function `directory-name-p` isn't defined - you'll get an error in that case. Define a replacement for it, that tests whether the file-name string ends in `/`, and use that.

Comment: I didn't get that error, the prompt showed just fine as mentioned in my [previous comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71506/create-file-with-ffap-if-it-doesnt-exist#comment115546_71510), although I did not hit enter to validate, because the prompt didn't get populated with the full path to the desired file.